# Location to store images in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image

So I'm making the transition from BlueJ to Eclipse like any good college Freshman would and I can't, for the life of me, Find where to store an image in the workspace which would allow me to access it from my code. any ideas?

Comment: Can you more explain your context application please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you store your images in a resources folder.

Here's an example from one of my projects.

[image: Kakurasu Folder Structure]

My images are stored in an images folder, which is included in the Java classpath.

I read them with a method call:

```
model.setCheckMark(readImage("/check_mark.png"));
```

And here's the readImage method:

```
private Image readImage(String streamString) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(streamString));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project on the left side-bar and create a 'New -> Source Folder'. A common mistake and one I made is to simply create a 'New -> Folder'. This wont work and I can relate to anyones frustrations at this and similar hurdles when moving from BlueJ to a proper IDE like Eclipse.